# Configure spark in dockerfile

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, apache-spark, pyspark, jupyter-lab

I am using jupyter/pyspark-notebook docker image but I did not find any support of delta and s3 so I manually tried to set up all the required things like below code and then it works fine.

```
import pyspark
spark = pyspark.sql.SparkSession.builder.master("local[4]").appName('SparkDelta') \
        .config("spark.sql.extensions", "io.delta.sql.DeltaSparkSessionExtension") \
        .config("spark.sql.catalog.spark_catalog", "org.apache.spark.sql.delta.catalog.DeltaCatalog") \
        .config("spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.impl", "org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem") \
        .config("spark.jars.packages", 
                "io.delta:delta-core_2.12:1.2.1,"
                "org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-aws:3.3.1,"
                "com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-bundle:1.12.180") \
        .config('spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.access.key', 'xxxxx') \
        .config('spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.secret.key', 'xxxxx') \
        .getOrCreate()
df = spark.read.csv("s3a://<bucket>/<folder>/test33.csv")
print(df)
```

but exposing credentials and setting up all the jars and the packages like above approach does not seems to be a good approach, so I wanted to have all these things setup while starting the docker container. So, can we have all the config options mentioned above in dockerfile and then directly use the spark object when the container is up and running?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the environment variables in the Dockerfile. For example, you can set the access key in the Dockerfile in this way:

```golang
ENV ACCESS_KEY "XXXX"
```

and then in the code:

```py
import os
import pyspark

spark = pyspark.sql.SparkSession.builder.master("local[4]")\
    .appName('SparkDelta')\
    .config('spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.access.key', os.environ['ACCESS_KEY']) \
    .getOrCreate()
```

same for the other keys.

By doing so, you won't expose your keys in the file and you will able to change them smoothly using the Dockerfile (you could also use a docker compose btw)